# Platform-specific dependency creeping into Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have implemented a graph editor with Eclipse EMF and GMF frameworks. After completing my project, I realized that this plugin shows dependencies (not explicitly added by me) on some OS-specific plugins.i.e:`org.eclipse.ui.win32`, `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86`. And whenever I have tried to bypass this dependency at my update site something went wrong with the installation process of the plugin.

As such it is impossible to run my plugin in *nix environment or even win64 machines.This seems a very heavy constraint dependency to me. Am I doing something in a wrong way? Or is there no other way of building Eclipse plugins which are cross-platform other than building the project from scratch at each different OSs?

Comment: Why does it use those OS-specific plugins?

Comment: As a final step of my building process i made a feature plugin and afterwards an Update project to upload the plugin online.At the feature plugin creation i declare my plugins that consist the graph creator and then the Feature in an automatic way it fills a list of plugins that depend on these.In this list there are those 2 win32 plugins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We created a similar style of plug-in in my project. Under "Plug-in Dependencies" in Package Explorer I can see org.eclipse.swt.win32 listed, but it is *not* listed in required plug-ins in plugin.xml.

We also successfully created an update site which works for Mac users without issue.

So, yes it is possible to have a cross-platform plug-in.

I would suggest you first try to to use "Export..." -> "Deployable plug-ins and fragments" to create a bunch of jar files for your plug-in. See if these can be successfully installed by copying into the drop-ins folder of a fresh eclipse installation. Do this first on a Win32 install, then try on another platform. Once you have that working, use the new Eclipse installation to create the Update site.

Comment: I agree; this should just work. Iraklis sees the win32 plugins because Eclipse resolved these in his installation. If his plugin is installed on Linux, Eclipse should switch to the Linux variant automatically.

Comment: I think i realized my "bug".When i build the feature plugin, in which i include my plugins at the Dependencies tab i'd checked the button: "Compute" which makes a list with plugin dependencies from the existing working environment.In the meanwhile as Adrian mentioned in the plugins list the *win32 dependencies are there but now not in dependencies list